# How do I get a label to display random text When a button is pressed (no repeat)?

Tags: swift

I'm completely new to Swift and working with my first app where random text is displayed. The text must not be repeated, when all the text is displayed, the user should be notified that all the text is displayed.

I have received random text to work but not no repeat and not the user should be notified that all the text is displayed.

Anyone have suggestions on how I should do?

I use Xcode Version 7.3.1

```
let quotes: NSArray = ["Text0.", "Text1.", "Text2.", "Text3.", "Text4.", "Text5.", "Text6.", "Text7."]

let range: UInt32 = UInt32(quotes.count)

let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
let QuoteString = quotes.objectAtIndex(randomNumber)
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Sorry I forget the code

Comment: do not put your code in the comment. Edit your question and add the code there

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the random-stuff in GamePlayKit, so I'd use a GKRandomSource like this.

```
import GameplayKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

let quotes = ["Text0.", "Text1.", "Text2.", "Text3.", "Text4.", "Text5.", "Text6.", "Text7."]
let shuffledQuotes = GKRandomSource().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(quotes) as! [String]

for quote in shuffledQuotes {
    print(quote)
}

print("All the text has been displayed")
```

This isn't hooked up to a button or anything but I'm sure you'll be able to work that out...

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response